# Having a problem with boost::filesystem::remove_all in windows 10

Tags: c++, boost, access-denied

I have written a code which is going to work in Windows 10 and Windows 7 as well. I have used boost::filesystem::remove_all in order to remove a directory in D:/dummyFolder. The problem is the code works fine on Windows 10; however, I have got an exception in Windows 7, as below:

```
boost::filesystem::remove: Access is denied: "D:\dummyFolder\dummyFile.*"
```

There is not any problem with Windows 10 but Windows 7.
In either cases, the user has been set to be the Administrator and has the permission to write, delete and etc.

Comment: I am afraid the given information is too narrow to help you solving this problem.

Comment: One reason could be that one of the files is actually in use (regardless of  Windows 10 or 7).

Comment: I kinda seem to remember a bug in this area. You might be able to find it in release notes and solve by upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been addressed using std::filesystem (C++17) instead of boost package. It seems it is kind of bug related to boost; however, I was out of time to update my boost package into a newer one.